# How to assign the variable to a button asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am passing variable from controller to view using ViewBag. Controller part:

```
ViewBag.Counter = count;
```

In my view I make a button and I want to assign button value to this variable, every time you press the button you get the variable. That is my code in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "Probe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return myFunction()" }))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <br />
            <input class="inner" type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnSubmit" />
            <button class="inners" value="@ViewBag.Counter">But</button>                 
            <button>@Html.ActionLink("View Domain Name", "Domain",  "Probe") </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I press the button it gives me some weird line: ["\u003cul\u003e","\u003cli\u003ePlease choose Excel file\u003c/li\u003e","\u003c/ul\u003e"] 
and I see in my address bar that it redirects to http://localhost:54570/Probe/UploadExcel It should show we the variable value instead.

Comment: What you mean _doesn't work for me_?  Try also `@ViewBag.Counter` without brackets and be sure `count` is not null or empty

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: Add your action method `UploadExcel` also. You want only call  your method and pass file and counter value?

Comment: I don't get your part with action method. I have action method in controller UploadExcel. it contains many things. I uploading excel data to sql server then just simply count the rows been inserted. and pass the variable from controller to view like that ViewBag.Counter = count;  If I just trying simply display the rows in my view  @ViewBag.Counter I see the number but whenever I try to assign to the button it does't work. Sorry if I explaining in a wrong words I am new to ASP.net and just learning.

Comment: I know what you're doing before getting this value, but the question is what you want  to do with this value next? You are clicking button and you want redirect where?

Answer (score 0):

`<button class="inners" value="@ViewBag.Counter">@ViewBag.Counter</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I got you point M. Wiśnicki. I created new View then add action method to controller and pass the counter to that view. The button I have in my main view "Index" so I just simply call the method when press the button

`<a href="@Url.Content("~/Probe/TotalEntries")"> 
   <input type="button"value="Total Records" />
 </a>`

which redirects to the view and displays the counter (number of rows inserted).